# convert ajax variable to use them in c# clases

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables, asp.net-mvc-5

I call an `action` by ajax in my MVC5 project.That action returns the result to ajax success function. I want to use those result in **C#** code below - for example: `persiancalander.GetDayOfMonth(' ')` but I don't know how to do it.
pleaseeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee helppppppppppppppppppppp

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script>
    function f2(value) {
        var ID = value;
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/GetNext",
            data: { ID: ID },
                    type:"post",
                    success: function (value) {
                        results = JSON.parse(value);
                        $("#mydiv").empty();
                        $.each(results, function (idx, result) {
                            var d = result.datatime;
                            @{
                                PersianCalendar p = new PersianCalendar();
                                p.GetDayOfMonth(d)/ p.GetMonth(resul) /                          p.GetYear(item.datatime);       
                                }


                        })
                    }
                })
      }
</script>




 public string GetNext(int ID)
        {


      TempData["ID"] = ID;
                ID = ID - 1;
List<news> news = db._NewsRepository.GETAllItems().Skip(4 * ID).Take(4).ToList();
                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                return js.Serialize(news.Select(x => new { ID = x.ID, img = x.img, matn = x.matn, title = x.title, dateatime = x.datatime, comments = x.comments}));
        }
```

Comment: where's your action?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use the dates that returns from the server? Can you show us how the date looks like? Also, do you know the [`date`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) object in JavaScript?

Comment: Yes .I want To use date returned From Server in This p.GetDayOfMonth(d) Function